# Verificar resposta correta

Tags: jquery

Boa tarde,
Estou fazendo um form de perguntas e respostas simples. Gostaria de saber como faço para **caso** a resposta seja a **errada**, mostre a alternativa correta no alert.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var marcado = this.value;

    if (marcado == "S") {
      alert("Correto");
    } else {
      alert("Errado");
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
  <p>Primeira pergunta de teste:</p>
</h3>

<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 1
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> Resposta certa
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 2
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Os textos, que são as respostas, vem a seguir do elemento, então em DOM você pode usar o `nextSibling` (em jQuery na API tem o `.next()`, mas **não é a mesma coisa**), então ficaria algo como:

```
 $('[name="r"][value="S"]').get(0).nextSibling.textContent;
```

Desta forma você irá pegar o texto a seguir do elemento desejado (no caso o elemento com a resposta correta), exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var marcado = this.value;

    if (marcado == "S") {
      alert("Correto");
    } else {
      var resposta = $('[name="r"][value="S"]').get(0).nextSibling.textContent;
      alert("Errado, a resposta correta seria: " + resposta);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
  <p>Primeira pergunta de teste:</p>
</h3>

<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 1
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> Resposta certa
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 2
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 3
```

No entanto você pode simplificar e até evitar acidentes criando elementos para separar as respostas ao invés de usar `<br>`, desta forma você poderá ter várias perguntas na mesma página, exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(".resposta input[type='radio']").click(function() {
    var marcado = this.value;

    if (marcado == "S") {
      alert("Correto");
    } else {
      console.log($(this).parents('.pergunta').find('[name="r"][value="S"]').parent().get(0))
      var resposta = $(this).parents('.pergunta').find('[name="r"][value="S"]').parent().text().trim();
      alert("Errado, a resposta correta seria: " + resposta);
    }
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pergunta">
    <h3>
      <p>Primeira pergunta de teste:</p>
    </h3>

    <div class="resposta">
         <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 1
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
         <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> Resposta certa
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
        <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 2
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
        <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 3
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pergunta">
    <h3>
      <p>Segunda pergunta de teste:</p>
    </h3>

    <div class="resposta">
         <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Pedro Álvares Cabral
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
         <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> Graham Bell
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
        <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> George Washington
    </div>
    <div class="resposta">
        <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Thomas Edison
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Porque esta aparecendo esses caracteres? https://prnt.sc/p8c8mn

Comment: @Tiago aqui não apareceu nenhum caractere assim, teste no botão EXECUTAR acima, os dois exemplos (o segundo é melhor) ... esses caracteres parece um outro problema fora deste script, se você tiver como colocar online para eu testar ou enviar o arquivo facilitaria para identificar, mas repito, o problema não é no script da resposta, é em outro lugar.

Answer (score 2):

Cara é só colocar dentro da condição para mesmo clicando no errado ele marcar o certo. Então se marcar a errada ele da o alerte e faz um `:checked` no `input` com `name="r" value="S"` tipo assim `$('[name="r"][value="S"]').prop("checked", true);`. Dessa forma vc assegura que apenas o `input` com `value="S"` pertencente ao radio-group de `name="r"` vai ser marcado (Obrigado @AndersonCarlosWoss pela observação)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='radio']").click(function() {
        var marcado = this.value;

        if (marcado == "S") {
            alert("Correto");
        } else {
            alert("Errado");
            $('[name="r"][value="S"]').prop("checked", true);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
[value="S"]:checked {
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>
    <p>Primeira pergunta de teste:</p>
</h3>

<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 1
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> Resposta certa
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 2
<br>
<input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="N"> Resposta errada 3
```

Comment: Ao invés de `$('[value="S"]')` é melhor fazer `$('[name="r"][value="S"]')` para garantir que pegará a opção correta da mesma pergunta (alterando `r` dinamicamente conforme a pergunta), isso considerando que poderão existir múltiplas perguntas na página. E tenho dizer que é esquisito ter 4 radios com o mesmo `value` :x

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito bem observado, até fiz um edit na resposta ;)

Comment: Mas não é marcar a resposta correta se ele marcar a errada. Somente aparecer no **alert** o texto correspondente a resposta correta.

Comment: @Tiago nesse caso eu só saberi te responder se o texto seguido do Radio estivesse dentro de uma tag, tipo se estivesse assim: <input name="r" type="radio" class="ace" value="S"> <span>Resposta certa</span>
<br> eu conseguira pegar. No entento, parece que a resposta do Guilherme vai te atender nesse ponto.

Comment: @hugocsl apesar do nextSibling atender inicialmente o segundo exemplo de minha resposta mostra como fazer se precisar de multiplas perguntas na mesma página.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu está lendo ela agora mesmo rss, realmente a forma como vc estruturou o HTML ajuda muito a controlar as coisas. Isso deve acontecer bastante quando "designer" faz o HTML, e depois passa para o Dev. fazer o código haha

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, preciso dizer que o seu HTML não fez muito sentido e parece ser mal planejado. Você tem uma lista que não está como lista; você possui 5 opções de resposta para cada pergunta, mas na verdade tem apenas 2, pois o que é considerado será o `value` do elemento `input[type=radio]`. Isto é, o texto "associado" ao `input` não fará diferença para a semântica. Quando você quer associar um texto ao campo, deverá utilizar o `label`.

Deveria ser algo assim:

```html
<div id="pergunta-1">
  <h1>Enunciado da pergunta</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-1" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="1" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-1">Opção 1 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-2" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="2" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-2">Opção 2 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-3" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="3" data-correta="S">
      <label for="opcao-3">Opção 3 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-4" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="4" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-4">Opção 4 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-5" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="5" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-5">Opção 5 errada</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Veja que o `value` das opções é um valor que identifica aquela opção. Neste exemplo eu utilizei os valores de 1 a 5 representando os ids das opções, mas poderia ser qualquer valor que identifique aquela opção naquela pergunta. O controle de qual opção é a correta foi passada para o atributo `data-correta`.

Assim, com o JavaScript, ficaria:

```js
$("input[type=radio]").on("change", function() {
  if (this.dataset.correta === 'N') {
    // Exibe a resposta correta:
    alert($(`input[name="${this.name}"][data-correta="S"] + label`).text());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<fieldset id="pergunta-1">
  <h1>Enunciado da pergunta</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-1" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="1" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-1">Opção 1 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-2" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="2" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-2">Opção 2 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-3" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="3" data-correta="S">
      <label for="opcao-3">Opção 3 correta</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-4" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="4" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-4">Opção 4 errada</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="opcao-5" type="radio" name="respostas-1" value="5" data-correta="N">
      <label for="opcao-5">Opção 5 errada</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Onde `input[name="${this.name}"][data-correta="S"]` buscará a resposta correta para aquela pergunta e o `+ label` seleciona o `label` associado ao `input`, exibindo o seu texto. Outra opção seria selecionar o `label` a partir do valor do `for` através do `id` da opção correta.

Como as perguntas possuirão um grupo de respostas que serão independentes das opções das outras perguntas, é conveniente utilizar o `<fieldset>` para agrupar os elementos semanticamente relacionados dentro do formulário.

Comment: Dataset + label .... muito elegante! Só faltou colocar dentro de um fieldset haha. E olha isso que massa, das antigas.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/radiogroup

Comment: @hugocsl e inclusive seria interessante colocar cada pergunta dentro de um `fieldset` para definir a independência entre elas, mesmo pertencendo ao mesmo `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um modelo em JavaScript Puro, sei que não pediu :)
Tem outros jeitos de fazer mais este também é bem prático e bem simples.

```
    var ace = window.document.getElementsByName('r');

    ace[0].addEventListener('click', function (){
        if(ace != 'S'){alert('Resposta Errada')}
        return ace[1].checked = true;
    })
    ace[1],
    ace[2].addEventListener('click', function (){
        if(ace != 'S'){alert('Resposta Errada')}
        return ace[1].checked = true;
    })
    ace[3].addEventListener('click', function (){
        if(ace != 'S'){alert('Resposta Errada')}
        return ace[1].checked = true;
    })
```

e se você não quiser que marque o botão correto é só apagar os `return ace[1].checked = true;` e caso queria dar um `alert('Resposta correta')` é só por assim :

```
ace[1].addEventListener('click', function (){
        if(ace != 'N'){alert('Resposta Correta')}

    })
```